# React Apollo GraphQL - Is it possible to filter the cached results while waiting for the server results

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

Using react with apollo client for graphql. When we already have some data in the cache and we are fetching the same query with different variables for filtering by a search string, can we filter the `data` locally while we are waiting for the server results?

```
const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(QUERY, { variables: { searchString } };
useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredData(data.filter(x => x.name.includes(searchString)));
}, [data])
```